# Fazer um parser de uma pagina

Tags: php, symfony-2, parser, web-crawler

Estou tentando pegar as informações de uma pagina pela url. Estou desenvolvendo em symfony e usando simple_html_dom ou o Crowler. Mas não chego nem perto de fazer o que preciso.

A pagina que estou acessando é essa: [Eventos SESC São Carlos](http://www.sescsp.org.br/programacao/#/tagcloud=nuvem/ct=o-que-fazer)

O que quero fazer é pegar todos os titulos dos eventos. Por enquando estou com esse codigo abaixo onde pego a pagina e dou um find pela div com a classe `block_agenda-container` que é a classe que separa os eventos. Porem não me retorna nada.

```
$html = new \simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file('http://www.sescsp.org.br/programacao/#/tagcloud=nuvem/ct=o-que-fazer');
$ret = $html->find('div[class=block_agenda-container]');
dump($ret);
die();
```

Comment: O conteúdo provém de requsições Ajax. Para obter os dados, faça a requisição diretamente a fonte que retorna os dados que interessa. A URL é essa: `http://www.sescsp.org.br/programacao/ajax/filtroView.action`

Comment: Entendi. Mas duas perguntas: Primeiro como você descobriu isso? E segundo como ficaria a requisição?

Comment: Beleza por enquanto e só um teste, por isso tinha perguntado com você achou a rora, para em outra paginas eu conseguir fazer o mesmo, caso vc tenha usado alguma ferramenta ou algo do tipo. Mas valeu!!!

Comment: @MarciusLeandro você pode descobrir a origem de uma request AJAX via  [Firefox network inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) (ou ferramenta análoga, no Chrome). Então você precisa somente filtrar por `XHR`. Veja aqui um exemplo: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32719464/1262820